# Using XPath can ID/IDREF use be checked?

Tags: xpath

With XML Schema we can define ID/IDREF links between components in an XML document. I'm looking for a way, using XPath, to ensure that only certain IDs can be used as IDREFs - i.e. only those values which logically make senses in the context of the schema design.

Using the example below, how do I ensure that a book's library_id is actually one of the available library_ids and not some other id which could appear in the  message and be used for some entirely different purpose (but still be schema valid).

```
<books>
    <book library_id="lib1">
        <author>A</author>
        <title>B</title>
    </book>
    <book library_id="lib2">
        <author>C</author>
        <title>D</title>
    </book>
    <library id="lib1">
        <name>X</name>
        <city>Y</city>
    </library>
    <library id="lib2">
        <name>X</name>
        <city>Y</city>
    </library>
</books>
```

The closest I've come to getting this to work is to use the XPath contains function e.g.

```
contains(//library/@id,//book/@library_id)
```

but this throws an error because a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains() ("lib1","lib2").

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I hope that understood correctly what you want

Books with library_id present in library list

```
//book[@library_id = //library/@id]
```

Books with incorrect library_id

```
//book[not(@library_id = //library/@id)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use XSD's key/keyref constraints instead of ID/IDREF? These are much more flexible: they can be scoped to any element rather than the whole document; you can have different kinds of IDs within a document and the refs must match up to the same kind; the values can be composite (e.g. first name + last name); the values can be of any data type.

Comment: We need to stick with the use of the ID attribute which is optional in our schema, and this gives us an issue when trying to use key/keyref.

Comment: Then you will have to live with its limitations. But I'm not aware of many things you can do with ID/IDREF that you can't do with key/keyref.